# Pass phalcon route value to angularjs

Tags: angularjs, phalcon, phalcon-routing

Not able to pass phalcon route key to angularjs

**Route:**
    
    `//Define a route
    $router->add(
        "userList",
        array(
            "controller" => "user",
            "action"     => "get",
        )
    );`

**With in AngularJs:**
    
      `this.getUsers = function() {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.get("userList")
            .success(function(data) {
                defer.resolve(data);
            })

            return defer.promise;
        }`

    
    With in angularjs if i pass route value directly like (user/get i.e controllername/action) then everything works fine but if i pass route key(userList) it is showing error as "**UserlistController handler class cannot be loaded**"

I want to pass route key(userList) not its value(user/get)

Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my routes I have a leading slash /

```
//Define a route
$router->add(
    "/userList",
    array(
        "controller" => "user",
        "action"     => "get",
    )
);
```

and

```
$http.get("/userList")
```

That should work. However if you are creating a new project and don't need to support legacy urls, I would suggest just using the default routes, it is less code so it will be simpler, and might run a little bit faster.